# Can you turn off UAC for a single app?

Tags: windows-7, windows, uac

I'm running windows 7 RC.

I've got a few poorly-designed apps that force me to click through a UAC box in order to launch them. This is becoming quite an annoyance. I don't mind UAC aside from this issue.

Is there a way to stop UAC from popping up for just one particular app or executable?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can, using the Application Compatibility Toolkit:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=24DA89E9-B581-47B0-B45E-492DD6DA2971&displaylang=en

More info on using the toolkit here:
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/window-on-windows/?p=635

Comment: The ACT method doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: There seems to be no way to turn it of on a per application basis if you need to run an unsigned application as administrator (Far Manager in my case)

Answer (score 3):

There is a work-around that lets you create a shortcut that runs the program in administrator mode, without triggering the UAC. It utilizes the Task Scheduler. This is really a bit of a security hole, and it might be patched one day, but it is supposed to work for both Vista and 7. See [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-administrator-mode-shortcuts-without-uac-prompts-in-windows-vista/) from the How-to Geek.

Comment: This helped me to run a program as admin at logon without the UAC annoying me every time. I don't think this will be patched because there are many business tasks that depend on automated nightly tasks that require admin priviledges, such as backups. I don't think Mirosoft will tell those companies to hire an admin to click away the UAC at 4 AM :D

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, you have to either have it on completely, or turn it off completely.

Comment: This is not true for every app.  There seem to be work around to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the individual app or shortcut to always run as an administrator. That should only make you click the approval box once, when it starts up, but it varies by the application.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me...apps still require UAC approval every time, even after changing the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

if this can be of any additional help to anyone - try this

http://www.door2windows.com/how-to-turn-off-user-account-control-uac-for-a-specific-application/

download link : 
http://www.itknowledge24.com/downloads.html

it is a simple tool to create a trusted shortcut