# Grant permanent UAC permission to one program?

Tags: windows-7, security, uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selectively disabling UAC for specific programs on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/99286/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-7)

Is there a way to grant permanent UAC permission in Windows 7 to a single program?  I have an old program that's supposed to start up in the background when Windows starts.  I want to have it "just work" without the nagging, but keep UAC in all other cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try creating a UAC Whitelist.  http://www.beingmanan.com/wp/2008/06/create-uac-white-list/ has instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting it to run as Administrator?

Find the executable -> right click -> properties -> tab compatability -> check "Run this program as administrator" (bottom of the dialog)

Now, I do not know if this would cause issues with running it as a background process, but at the very least if you just put it into the Start folder (under the start menu), I would imagine you would be prompted by UAC when the program begins, which is when you log in, and then from that point on the program should run as administrator with full access.

Comment: It still prompts me every time I start the program.

Comment: I do not think you will be able to get around that. The program will need explicit permission to run with administrative privileges when it starts to actually have those privileges. The only applications that don't do this under Windows 7 is some of the software Microsoft ships with Windows 7. But if you run this as a background process surely it would only start up once per login / reboot?