# Disable UAC prompt for certain executables

Tags: windows-7, security, uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selectively disabling UAC for specific programs on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/99286/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-7)

Is it possible on Windows 7 to run a certain executable as Aministrator without UAC prompt and without disabling system-wide UAC prompt?

Comment: Check [Grant permanent UAC permission to one program?](http://superuser.com/questions/134597/grant-permanent-uac-permission-to-one-program)

Comment: This is a dupe.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Control panel and double click the user accounts and profiles icon in category view and then click towards the bottom in the dialogue box that says User Account Control Access and then move your slider down to one or two levels above completely off. In Windows 7 you have 4 options on how intrusive you want the UAC control setting to be.

In vista it was simply on or off with no in between setting that you could set it to. I keep mine completely off for home usage. I recommend keeping it partially on for a business network. Just look for your preferred setting and set it to it. Read the setting descriptions in the right hand pane of the UAC control settings window. This is the best method I know to fix your issue.

Comment: This does it for all programs, when the question asks how to do it for specific programs.

Comment: Sorry, but I was asking "without disabling system-wide UAC prompt"