# Whitelist .EXE in UAC? - WIndows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, uac, msconfig

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elevated Priviliges for Startup Applications in Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/46/elevated-priviliges-for-startup-applications-in-vista)
>   [Selectively disabling UAC for specific programs on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/99286/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-7)
>   [Grant permanent UAC permission to one program?](https://superuser.com/questions/134597/grant-permanent-uac-permission-to-one-program)

How can I whitelist a specific application so I don't have to get the dreadful propt each time I login? It's actually an .exe patch needed and located in the startup programs in msconfig.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot selectively disable UAC for certain applications, only disable UAC completely

Comment: I really hope there is a workaround, otherwise it's the biggest fail ever..

Comment: Remember using this workaround a while ago now actually, might be of use http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/27/act-suppressing-elevation-prompts-for-legacy-applications.aspx

Comment: I really hate installing third party stuff :/

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid a UAC prompt by running the executable as a scheduled task that starts when a user logs in.

When creating the task, make sure you check the box "run with highest privileges".

More details at http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-programs-elevated-without-getting-the-uac-prompt/