# Allowing a program that requires admin rights to bypass UAC

Tags: windows-7, uac, everything

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selectively disabling UAC for specific programs on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/99286/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-7)

I use a (desktop) search engine called [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/), which needs to be started at Windows startup, since it has to build an index of all files or something. It then sits in a system tray icon, ready to be used.

Now, this program needs admin rights, and it gets annoying to have to type my password at a UAC prompt each time I log in. I heard that you can allow an application to run with admin rights while not prompting for a password with the Task Scheduler, so I tried it. The trick does work, but it's not useful: the system tray icon for Everything doesn't appear, and starting the program from the Start menu opens a new instance of the process instead of just a search window from the active process.

So my question is: is there a way to make Everything start automatically after login, without a UAC prompt?

Comment: The question linked as duplicate doesn't work. I already tried that; my problem is that I can't use Everything with that method because there's no icon in the system tray.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "exceptions" list for the UAC that you can add your program to.

If you are signed in as an administrator: 
According to http://www.tweak-uac.com/home/, you can make UAC be quiet, so, do so and it should no longer prompt you.

If you are not an administrator: 
Do the above and...Use CPAU to create job file, create a batch file that'll run CPAU with your job file, stick that batch file in your startup and that should be that.

If this fails, stick the batch somewhere, create a shortcut to the batch and in the shortcuts properties, set it to run only as an Administrator.

http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/index.htm

Goodluck