# Run certain applications as administrator by default

Tags: windows-7, administrator

Every time I want to start a program that modifies files and stuff I have to "run it as administrator", otherwise it won't function correctly.

Can I somehow run it as admin by default?

I dropped some app shortcuts in my taskbar and none of them are running as admin... And If I right-click the icons I don't get that "run as admin..." option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selectively disabling UAC for specific programs on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/99286/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-7)

Comment: The OP did not mention UAC.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut that you place in the program menu -> start and in the properties of the shortcut you just have to go to the "Compatibility" tab and check "Run as ...

Or, yo open the regular context menu (to access Properties) of an already pinned shortcut, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right-click the pinned shortcut.

If you would like more info check [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx)

Comment: ok that works, but I still get the annoying pop-up "do you want to allow this program...". Can I disable that too?

Comment: Yes you can.  Click Start -> type msconfig -> Go to tools -> Check the " Change UAC Settings " -> Launch -> Drag the Bar all the way Down .... Restart and you are OK

Comment: @Anna: It's not a good idea to do this, but if you want to go back to the bad old days when you had a lot of malware problems, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

If your user is administrator you can turn UAC off, and as far as I know all programs will run as administrator, and without having to authentication.