# How do I get around UAC in window 7 for a reboot with the option to abort

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

I've been using PSshutdown remotely on our Windows XP machines for our weekly reboots because of its ability to reboot with the ability to abort the operation. I use ShTasks to create the weekly task.

The Problem is on Windows 7 the task is created but never executes because of UAC even when I run the batch using an administrator command line, or with the elevate privileges switch.

I saw another user "Bob" created a program called idleshutdown.exe which does something similar.  Not sure how his program gets around UAC.

Comment: Do any of the answers on [Selectively disabling UAC for specific programs on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/99286/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-7) help at all?

Comment: I will try Microsoft Act, but I don't have high hopes there.  I'm running this with an domain administrator password for psshutdown and in my batch to run it remotely which seems like it should work, but doesn't.

Comment: ACT didn't cut it, now looking into Beyond Trusts Privilege Manager.

Comment: solved the problem..Used the -h switch with PSExec when Creating the task with SHTasks, and use the /RL Highest flag with PSShutdown. The task now runs with highest privileges.  Now the only issue is the interactive services notification in windows 7.  The message only appears when you click the notification on the taskbar.

Comment: if you solved the problem you can post it as an answer and you should be able to accept it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem.

Used the `-h` switch with PSExec when Creating the task with SHTasks, and use the `/RL` Highest flag with PSShutdown. The task now runs with highest privileges.

Now the only issue is the interactive services notification in windows 7. Also, Windows XP doesn't like the `/RL` Highest, so I had to modify the script to identify the operating system and only use the `/RL` Highest switch on Windows 7.