# How do I get Java Available Update *Notification* (jucheck.exe) to run on its own without prompting for "run as administrator" permission first?

Tags: windows-7, java, administrator, automatic-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selectively disabling UAC for specific programs on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/99286/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-7)

When I start up my machine, after a short while, the entire screen is dimmed with a brighter pop-up window in the middle saying that jucheck.exe wants to run. This is distracting and annoying, in-your-face and rather shabby. I actually DO want the program to run to *check* for Java updates but I want it to run without Windows asking me if I will allow it to run first.

(I know what this program is: This is the program from Oracle, part of the standard java installation, that checks to see if Java updates are available. I do not want to get into debates about the merits of Java and whether you should run it or not, for me, I wish to run it.)

It is, after all, just the program that *checks* for available updates. I can still choose whether or not to actually download and run the updates.

My extensive searching here and elsewhere seems to just find answers that state to disable the update checker from running. This may suit those people who do not need Java, but I do use Java so those answers are NOT the solution I need.

I have found the location of jucheck.exe: on Windows 7 it is here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Java\Java Update` along with other files: `jusched.exe` `jucheck.exe` `jaureg.exe` `jaucheck.exe`  I have gone into Properties for all of these and checked the box "Run this program as administrator" in the Compatibility tab, under the Privilege heading, and made this setting "for all users". I thought this would cure the problem, but it doesn't, I still get that pop up box, Windows asking my permission to run the program. I am baffled, as if I have told Windows to run this `jucheck.exe` as administrator then surely it now doesn't need to ask me (i.e. dim out the screen with a pop up box in the middle). The path to the program given in the pop-up box is the same as the one I have mentioned.

Please advise on what I need to do to get jucheck.exe to just run on its own to tell me that there are updates available. After all, Adobe updater checker doesn't need my permission, nor does Java EE Glassfish, Nokia PC Suite -- all of these other programs can run on their own to tell me updates available.

I am trying to do this on Windows 7 Home and Professional machines. These are home machines, not administered by an IT department in a Company (In fact on my work PC, the update checker just runs on its own without asking for permission first, so that it can inform me of updates available).

Comment: +1 @DragonLord yes, I have just used Task Scheduler to run jucheck.exe at highest privileges on user log on as described in the answers to the question that you mention. However my searching did not find that, and I guess others would be the same as me, because we would not think to use terms like "UAC", "disabling" in our search, rather we would use the terms I mention. So my question has validity in that it would help direct people to this original answer.

Comment: @therobyouknow - Nobody's suggesting this be *deleted*.  If it's closed as a duplicate, it directs people to the other question so it is in fact of use.

Comment: +1 thanks @Shinrai. I did try DragonLord's suggested answer in the other question, though it doesn't appear that jucheck.exe has run from   the Task Scheduler following restart. Further investigation on my part needed...