# Selectively disabling UAC for specific programs on Windows 7(tried other threads but no luck)

Tags: windows-7, windows, uac

I have a program which keeps on prompting when starting the windows.
I have searched lots threads even the thread on [Selectively disabling UAC for specific programs on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/99286/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-7)

I tried everything in there and doesn't work...

I even tried this site [4 Ways to Disable User Account Control (UAC) for Specific Software in Windows](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/task-scheduler-bypass-uac-prompt/)

Totally No Luck after trying all software, or going into task schedule myself and do it manually.  Anyone has any other idea how I can make this work?

Comment: What is the program you're having trouble with?

Comment: it's uniblue registry

Comment: Just remove it then, it's a garbage program

Comment: Canadian Luke> =.=" what do you suggest then?