# How to stop "User Account Control" from coming up on certain programs?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you turn off UAC for  a single app?](https://superuser.com/questions/2699/can-you-turn-off-uac-for-a-single-app)

Hi

I have windows 7 and I am wonder is there away to stop the "User Account Control" message from coming up on certain programs. Like I have Sql server 2005 and every time I launch it comes up with that message. I trust that program so I don't want an alert to be displayed.

Anyway to tern it off for certain applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This MSMVP blog entry](http://msmvps.com/blogs/martinzugec/archive/2008/05/16/ignore-uac-for-specific-programs.aspx) details what you're looking for. It covers how to completely bypass UAC for specific programs.  The general principle is to use scheduled tasks which are set to run with a very high level of trust (they run as "elevated" which allows them to run directly as an administrator).