# Force running a program as non-administrator in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, administrator, elevation

I've just installed, on Vista 32-bit, a program which in my opinion shouldn't require administrator rights. It's not installed in a system directory, and its purpose shouldn't obviously require any special privileges. However, the .exe has a UAC shield on it, and it asks me to elevate privileges immediately upon execution.

I'm prepared to risk it doing nasty things with the privileges of my user account, but not prepared to risk elevating it. Is there anything I can do short of setting up a virtual machine for it (or downloading the source and compiling it myself)?

(FWIW, the program in question is Pencil - pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Downloads/Application.aspx - but I'm more interested in general answers than app-specific ones).

Comment: You might wish to see [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/24631/prevent-elevation-uac-for-an-application-that-doesnt-need-it) and [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/39742/prevent-elevation-uac-for-an-unsigned-application), both of which are similar (but subtly different) and might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take from an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/24631/prevent-elevation-uac-for-an-application-that-doesnt-need-it) to a similar question:

> For all apps with `requestedPrivilegeLevel="highestLevel"` in their manifest, you can use [Microsoft's Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=24da89e9-b581-47b0-b45e-492dd6da2971&displaylang=en) to shim the application with the RunAsInvoker fix, which forces the app to run with your standard user tokens.
>
> For more information on how to use the Application Compatibility Toolkit ...(snip)... [general instructions](http://blogs.techrepublic.com/window-on-windows/?p=635).

Comment: The general instructions you link seem to say that this is actually doing the opposite: elevating without the UAC prompt.

Comment: @Peter, not quite (I had the links the wrong way round so you may have been on the wrong page, sorry about that, make sure you are looking [here](http://blogs.techrepublic.com.com/window-on-windows/?p=635) ), Figure E is setting the program to run "asInvoker" (ie, as the user calling the program, without elevation).

Comment: That's the one. It says "The RunAsInvoker option will allow the application to run with the same privileges and user rights as those of the parent process, which in this case is the Compatibility Administrator that you launched using the Run As Administrator command. Your application will run with full Administrator privileges."

Comment: @Peter - nuts, I think you're right. I'm sure I've done this before to un-elevate an executable... Unfortunatly I'm at work right now so can't verify. I wonder if one of the options or parameters contains something that needs tweaking (ie, to change the "invoker" to be the user, not the toolkit), I'll have to check this evening when I'm home...

Comment: @Peter - see [this Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638389(WS.10).aspx) and the quote `This fix specifies that the application does not require elevation.` This is getting a little bit ambiguous between the sources, but I think it may well work. It also suggests trying [SpecificNonInstaller](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638326(WS.10).aspx) to prevent Windows guessing that it is an installer and elevating because of that.

Comment: I see that there are also comments in the blog post correcting that, so it seems to be correct. I had a look at ACT, and it really seems like overkill. If I have to create a database and a network share to install the program which lets me work around the problem then I'll just give up. I'm not desperate enough to want to jump through all these hoops.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular program, you can get around the UAC requirement:

Instead of running Pencil normally, create a shortcut to `evolus\pencil\xulrunner.exe`, and then add `--app ..\app\application.ini` to the end, so the short cut is:

- `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Evolus\Pencil\xulrunner\xulrunner.exe" --app ..\app\application.ini`

This will let you run Pencil normally, without UAC.

Source: http://code.google.com/p/evoluspencil/issues/detail?id=275