# Setting a shortcut to trigger task scheduler

Tags: windows, shortcuts, uac, scheduled-tasks

I wanted to disable the UAC popup box when running the command prompt as admin, but [this](https://superuser.com/questions/2699/can-you-turn-off-uac-for-a-single-app) didn't work for me. What did work, was setting the task scheduler to run it as admin given a specific trigger. The problem is, I want it to run via shortcut, and not every time I log on or every day at 10pm.

Is there a way to set a shortcut as a trigger for task scheduler?
I figured this might have something to do with "Event" trigger, but I don't really know how it works.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[This](http://www.petri.co.il/bypass-uac-using-desktop-shortcut.htm) might help you out:

> 1. Click on the Start button, type Task
>      Scheduler in the "Start Search" box,
>      then press Enter. Note: You can get to
>      the Task Scheduler by using the Manage
>      My Computer context menu from the
>      "Computer" icon, by using the shortcut
>      from the Administrative Tools folder,
>      or by typing taskschd.msc in the Run
>      box.
> 2. In the Task Scheduler Management
>      Console , on the Actions pane click
>      Create Task.
> 3. In the Create Task window, type in the
>      name (and possibly the description) of
>      the task.  Click to select the “Run
>      With Highest Privileges” checkbox. You
>      do not need to change any other
>      settings. Note: Remember the name of
>      the task as we will need it later.
> 4. In the Actions tab click New. Browse for the program you want your
>      standard users to run without
>      requiring UAC. Click OK and you will see your task
>      entered into the Actions tab.
> 5. For laptop or portable computers that
>      might be running on batteries, go to
>      the Conditions tab and un-check the
>      “Start the Task only when computer is
>      Running on AC Power” check-box.
> 6. Go to the Settings tab and check that
>      the default check-boxes are selected.
>      Click OK when done.
> 7. Back in the Task Scheduler main window
>      you will now see the new task listed
>      under Scheduler Library with the
>      status of "Ready".
> 8. Close Task Scheduler. Right-click an
>      empty spot on your Desktop and select
>      New > Shortcut. In the Create Shortcut window enter
>      the following text:
>
>    `C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn "TaskName"`
>
>    Where "TaskName" is the
>      name of the task you chose, from step 3. **Note**: Include the quotation marks
>      around the TaskName or it will fail to
>      successfully run the task. Click Next and then enter a name for
>      the shortcut. When done, click Finish.
>
> Whenever you want to run the specified
>   program, simply double-click on the
>   shortcut you've created without
>   requiring UAC prompts or complete
>   Administrator access.
>
> You can also further customize the
>   shortcut with an icon or other
>   settings if you wish.
>
> You will need to repeat this steps
>   for any additional program you'll want
>   to use without the need to answer the
>   UAC prompts.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that the task name must *uniquely identify* the task, so you must make sure to use the correct path in the task name if the task is not in the root. For example, if you created a task-scheduler folder called `Startup` and then created a task called `foo bar`, you have to use `/tn "Startup\foo bar"`.

Comment: @Synetech Don't forgot the "Root" \ as well `"\Startup\foo bar"`