# Annoying programs that ask for Admin permissions on boot up

Tags: windows-7, uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you turn off UAC for a single app?](https://superuser.com/questions/2699/can-you-turn-off-uac-for-a-single-app)

Silly question: I am running Windows 7 Ultimate Edition, and having lapsed in my study of Windows, I do not know how to grant permissions for a program to run without prompting me whenever my computer reboots.

For example, I have a program from LG that checks for the latest updates / keys for my Blu-Ray drive whenever I log in. I am tired of it prompting me to let it run; how can I make it run without prompting?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Task in Windows Task Scheduler to run the application at log on or system starts up and mark it to run with highest privileges in task security options.

Here is how to do it:

1. Go to Start, type Task Scheduler and launch the scheduler
   application.
2. On right hand side there is Actions panel; Click "Create Basic Task..."
3. The wizard will guide you through the process of creating a task. Type a title, set trigger to "When the computer starts", action - start a program and choose the executable file you want to run. You can set to start the app just when particular user logs on in triggers tab on next step.
4. Before clicking finish button, mark the checkbox titled "Open the Properties dialog ..."
5. In propeties dialog lower left mark the checkbox "Run with highest privileges" and click OK.

Next time computer starts you will have the application running with elevated privileges. Just remember to remove the application from startup. I suggest to use Autoruns from Sysinternals. You can download it and other Sysinternals tools from Microsoft Technet - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new user account with administrative permissions, disable UAC for it, and have this program run under that account. I would advise though, this could be considered a security hole since it would allow any program to run as an administrator without prompting if it got ahold of that account.